# How do I make display a specific post based on what the day of the week it is?

Tags: templating, datetime

I can do it in PHP, but I'm having trouble converting it to twig.

Here's the PHP:

```php
$day = date("l");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');



if ($day == "Saturday")
{
    echo "<p><b>SATURDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>Half priced desserts</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$1 off Seasonal Pints</h3>";

}
elseif ($day == "Sunday")
{
    echo "<p><b>GAMEDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>One Free Kids Meal w/ each Adult Meal</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$3 on ALL Bottled Beers</h3>";    }
elseif ($day == "Monday")
{
    echo "<p><b>MONDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>$1 Tenders <br />(5 piece min.)</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$2 Lonestar Pints</h3>";  }
elseif ($day == "Tuesday")
{
    echo "<p><b>TUESDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>$.50 Boneless Wings <br /> (10 piece min.)</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$4 Margaritas</h3>";  }
elseif ($day == "Wednesday")
{
    echo "<p><b>WEDNESDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>Half price APPs!</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$3 shots of Jameson & Jager</h3>";
}
elseif ($day == "Thursday")
{
    echo "<p><b>THURSDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>2 for $10 Wingzup Burgers</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$3 Draft Beers all day</h3>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p><b>FRIDAY SPECIALS</b></p>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"mod1\">";
    echo "<p>FOOD</p>";
    echo "<h3>$2 Chili Pies</h3>";
    echo "<p>DRINK</p>";
    echo "<h3>$10 Pitchers (Bud Lt./Ziegenbock/Lone Star)</h3>";
}
```

Comment: You not gonna hardcode the daily menus into your template, Alex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the current date and time in Twig use the string [`"now"`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) and filter it with the [`date()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter to return it in the format you need (see the [list for supported parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

Then do the [`if` / `elseif`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) conditionals similar to how you'd do it in PHP. Another option would be to use the Craft specific [`switch`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/switch) tag.

```
{% switch "now" | date("l") %}

    {% case "Monday" %}
        {# Do Monday stuff #}

    {% case "Tuesday" %}
        {# Do Tuesday stuff #}

    {% case "Wednesday" %}
        {# Do Wednesday stuff #}

    {# etc. #}

{% endswitch %}
```